# XPath Delphi using MSXML

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

It's my first post and I have this situation:
How can I get attribute from xsd schema file using MSXML? It's possible or I need another way.
I'm using Delphi and MSXML 6.0.

Comment: Yes, it is possible; start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761367%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and go through it. There are code samples, so if you're reading that and still not finding what you need, please post a specific question on sample, with what your output should look like, and someone would be able to help you more effectively.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read the `xsd` schema file with [`IXMLDOMDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Here is an example:
(The example uses this [XML Schema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

```
uses ComObj, MSXML;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  xmlDoc: IXMLDOMDocument;
  node: IXMLDomNode;      
begin
  xmlDoc := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;
  xmlDoc.async := False;
  xmlDoc.load('C:\po.xsd');
  if xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
    raise Exception.Create('XML Load error:' + xmlDoc.parseError.reason);
  node := xmlDoc.selectSingleNode('//xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name="purchaseOrder"]');
  ShowMessage(node.attributes.getNamedItem('type').text); // "PurchaseOrderType"
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible; start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and go through it. There are code samples, so if you're reading that and still not finding what you need, please post a specific question on sample, with what your output should look like, and someone would be able to help you more effectively.

For anything but trivial, you should always use a specialized schema processor, typically labeled using the "SOM" acronym: Schema Object Model.

The code below shows major steps as excerpted from the page (it is VB, but should be easily converted to Deplhi).

```
Set oSchemaCache = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLSchemaCache.6.0")
' Load the schema.
nsTarget="http://www.example.microsoft.com/po"

oSchemaCache.add nsTarget, "po.xsd"
Set oSchema = oSchemaCache.getSchema(nsTarget)

For Each oA in oSchema.attributes
    result = result + printAttr(oA, t)
Next
```

Attributes associated with complex types can be processed similarly to this (the attributes are at the bottom):

```
Function processComplexType(oComplex, t)
    Dim res As String
    Dim strAny As String
    Dim oAttr As ISchemaAttribute

    res = printTab(t) + "<xsd:complexType"
    If oComplex.name <> "" Then
        res = res + " name='" + oComplex.name +"'"
    End If
    res = res + ">"

    If oComplex.contentType = SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_EMPTY Then
        res = res + printRemark("emtpy")
    End If
    If oComplex.contentType = SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_TEXTONLY Then
        res = res + printRemark("textonly")
    End If
    If oComplex.contentType =SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_ELEMENTONLY Then
        res = res + printRemark("elementonly")
        res = res + processGroup(oComplex.contentModel, t+1)
    End If
    If oComplex.contentType = SCHEMACONTENTTYPE_MIXED Then
        res = res + printRemark("mixed")
        res = res + processGroup(oComplex.contentModel, t+1)
    End If
    res = res + vbNewline
    If oComplex.baseTypes.length > 0 Then
        res = res + printRestrictions(oComplex, t+1)
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    StrAny = oComplex.anyAttribute.name
    If Err.number = 0 Then
        res = res + oComplex.anyAttribute.name
    End If

    For Each oAttr in oComplex.attributes
        res = res + printAttr(oAttr, t+1)
    Next

    processComplexType = res + printTab(t) + "</xsd:complexType>"+vbNewline
End Function
```

Comment: Hello all.
Sorry slow to respond to the post.
I managed to follow the logic that you gave me. Initially, my idea is to generate a TXT file with the fields of the XSD, but building on the restrictions that have these fields (maximum and minimum value, for example).
For example, I have an invoice, if the type of tax levied is X, you must generate a TXT file with the fields of this type of tax, but if Y, the same should be done, however, with Y.
In short, I want to generate txts of possibilities that have, for so I may be doing several tests and possible work around bugs.
(Sorry for my English)